What is correct test to investigate difference between two conditions with repeated measures per subject?
I am having trouble deciding what statistical test I should use for my data. I have 5 subjects who rated attractiveness of 20 objects and 20 sounds of the objects on a scale of 1-5. I would like to determine whether objects are rated as more attractive than sounds while accounting for difference between subjects.
First, I thought of using paired samples t-test where I compare ratings in every object-sound pair across all participants, i.e., 20 pairs in one subject, 100 pairs in total. But this doesn't seeem to be the right approach because it doesn't account for the subject.
I also thought of two-way repeated measures ANOVA where I have a condition A (presentation format) with two levels (object x sound) ,condition B (stimulus type) with 20 levels (i.e., dog, car, plane, ...), and subject as grouping variable. Is two-way repeated measures ANOVA a correct option?
I am not entirely conviced with this method because we do not have any prior hypothesis about the effect of the stimulus type. We could also average all ratings within-subject so that we have only two ratings per subject but this neglects the variability. Are there any more appropriate tests to investigate the difference in ratings of objects and sounds?

RM ANOVA makes assumptions that seem unlikely to be met here, primarily sphericity. One part of that is that all the covariances are equal. Also, RM ANOVA doesn't deal well with missing data, if you have any.
I think a better way to go is a multilevel model.
Also, you don't need a prior hypothesis to use ANOVA or MLM: The null is (almost always) that there is no effect or difference or relationship or whatever. And averaging across subjects loses a lot of power.

I apoligize if I do not provide an answer to your question, but I see many issues with the overall experiment. I will try to list them below. Maybe you can clarify some of them, and I can then procide a more suitable answer?

Your data comes from Likert scales. That data is ordinal, not interval scale. Hence, you can not perform any arithmetic on this data, just comparison; so t-tests, ANOVA, linear model are not valid mathematical manipulations of the data. If you had used Visual Analogue Scale (VAS), you could have made a case. But... Why so many studies still use Likert scales is beyond me, but that is for a different post.
Given this, you can not subtract the object score from the sound score, because you do not have an interval scale; $4-3 \ne 3-2 \ne 5-4$ $etc.$. Nor can you use a paired test (where you would subtract), or linear models or other such tests, where arithmetic would be done, assuming at least an interval scale.
You write "we do not have any prior hypothesis about the effect of the stimulus type". So why run an experiment, and try to analyze the data, if you are not clear about what you want to test? What else could you be investigating other than whether subjects prefer one type of stimuli? What is the variable of interest to you?; the subjects, or the stimuli type? Your question should have been asked before you conducted the experiment.
Your experiment uses 5 subjects. No matter what the result is, I doubt you will be able to convince anyone that your small sample is representative of the whole population of subjects.
Some authors have claimed that if you aggregate Likert scores (i.e. add them, or average them), then you can consider the sum a valid interval scale data (I have not seen a proper proof of that, but...). So you can add all the object scores, and all the sounds scores, and perform a paired t-test over your 5 subjects. But your sample size is now only 5, so your power will be (very?) low.
Alternatively, you could aggregate accross all 5 subjects, for each stimulus. Then do a paired t-test accross all 20 pairs. the power will be better. But this really tests the population of stimuli, not the population of subjects. I doubt that this is of interest to you?
You write "this doesn't seeem to be the right approach because it doesn't account for the subject". Also, you try to use "subject as grouping variable.". But you only have 5 subjects? What are you trying to infer about subjects? That Joe scores differently from Jane? What would be the point of this? Now, if you had 2 (or more) groups of subjects (separated e.g. by gender, age, etc.), you could look at differences between groups. But with only 5 subjects... So it is not clear what interesting conclusion you may be trying to reach, by subject.

